Is there any way to get any hardware id (IMEI/IMSI/mac) in android 10 and above
I need to access IMEI/IMSI/Mac address number of device.
Android 10 and above this is not possible.
Is there any way we can achieve this.
My application need any of this as the for security reason. Also, to identify one device one login
can we use deice proifle controller or work profile applcation?
How to use this .
Any example or any help will great.
Thanks is advance

All the values you list represent a privacy thread for the users of your application. They are therefore not available for normal applications.
If a unique identification criterion is required, the Advertising ID can be used. However, this is managed by the user and can, for example, be deleted by the user at any time.
Regarding the device policy controller (DPC), I assume this is what you mean by "deice proifle controller". This is a system used in the enterprise environment. If this were your case, then you would already have the necessary identifiers and would not need the values listed above.

is there any sample application for DPC? and what will registration process

There is a development guide, but you are late to the party... Google recommends using the Android Management API now
